# Is it possible to undervolt XPS 15 9560 - Kaby Lake 7700 CPU in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, undervolting, kaby-lake

Currently I cannot find any guides or examples of undervolting (outside of XTU) for the XPS 15 9560 (kaby lake 7700) from within Linux / Ubuntu.

Using TLP or other programs, is it possible to undervolt the CPU to reduce temperature / fan usage?

Comment: So your question is about methods to use to lower the voltage going to the CPU that what it's rated for, etc.?

Comment: Correct, artificially through software / bios lower the voltage going to the CPU in order to reduce fan and temperature. Commonly known as undervolting

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm also trying.

Comment: Have not sorry .

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this project](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/intel-undervolt/) through arch pacman. It's also on Github and apparently allows the setting of the max temperature, max TDP and changing of the voltage. I have not yet checked the code yet and because it's fairly new and no comments around it I wouldn't install it on my production machine without checking the code first.

The whole thing is based [on this](https://github.com/mihic/linux-intel-undervolt)

Comment: Interesting I'll have to give that a shot. Even though my OS is expendable on my spare XPS, it may damage hardware from what I can tell so would need someone with more expert knowledge to test

Comment: Afaik, undervolting can't damage your hardware. Otherwise running out of battery would do the same.